# Did malware take over my BIOS, preventing the utility from reading all of the blocks?

Tags: bios, malware

At one point I updated my BIOS to add UEFI version for Windows 8. I recently went back to Windows 7 after testing Windows 10 for a bit. However I have now found that my BIOS cannot be flashed, neither with the older version that doesn't include UEFI, nor with the UEFI ROM that was used previously.

The strangest part is that it seems to start at the "middle" of the blocks and then concludes that there isn't enough space for this ROM.

Could this be a sign of some kind of malware?

(Guids match, I know I have the correct ROMS)

[image]

(But it always starts halfway down and then thinks there isn't enough space: "3 - Error: ROM file size does not match existing BIOS size.")

[image]

Comment: Unlikely I guess. Even if there'd be some malware in the beginning, the flash tool would still try to start at it's hardcoded address (which would be 0). Have you tried saving your current BIOS image to a file? If you do so, is that file the same size as the new one? If not, add that information to your post.

Comment: For easier screenshots in the future: Just hit the "Print" key, which will put your current screen contents in your clipboard to be pasted in your preferred image editor.

Comment: @Mario I guess I could update it now, was out of range earlier and had previously took these to send over iMessage

Comment: The screenshots are fine, don't get me wrong, I just had the impression that you had more work with them than necessary.